# Inkscape: How do I make two nodes equidistant from two different nodes?

Tags: inkscape

Here's a practical example:

[image: Arrow]

I want to make the two highlighted sections equal in length. I tried playing with "Align and Distribute", but nothing seems to do the job. I was thinking a function that "takes the distance" of one node from the other and applies it to another pair of nodes. Is there anything in inkscape that works like that?

I know a few contrived ways to do it (like inputting coordinates manually or using another object as reference), but I was hoping for an elegant solution.

P.S. I am aware that there are better ways to make an arrow. I am just trying to learn.

Answer (score 6):

You could select the nodes you indicate, and rearrange them using the "Distribute Selected nodes Vertically" button. The other side of the rectangle won't follow the other nodes, and your arrow will be squint.

For example:

[image]

But then you could select the left rectangle nodes and the top and bottom vertices of the arrow head and Align again.

[image]

However, there is another way to make an arrow by aligning shapes instead:

Draw a rectangle, then use the Polygon tool to draw a triangle while holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you rotate it, to constrain the angle so that the left side of the triangle is vertical.

[image]

Move the triangle to overlap the rectangle, select both shapes, and then align using the "Centre on Horizontal Axis" button in the Align panel.

[image]

Once the objects have been aligned, select both rectangle and triangle, and click *Path > Union*

[image]

Comment: Distribute all four nodes vertically will certainly work, but it will always result in the width of the arrow's "trunk" being the same as the width of the two "protrusions".
I was thinking about having them different - e.g., a very thick arrow but with narrow "tip".

Comment: @Anton If that's what you want, then the second method I have described should be better, since the size of the rectangular trunk of the arrow won't be distorted at all.